# How to integrate JHipster application with onelogin

Tags: angularjs, jhipster, onelogin

I have developed on JHipster monolithic application with angular JS. Now I am looking to add my application into the **Onelogin** I am struggling to where to start and what to do? If you guys have any Idea please help me.

Comment: Key point is to use Spring Security SAML, have you tried this https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/spring-boot-security-saml ? and for nagular https://www.jasha.eu/blogposts/2015/10/saml-authentication-angularjs-spring-security.html  The JHipster staring point should probably use session auth type.

Comment: You could also potentially look into OIDC has well: https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect

Comment: I think OIDC is better and easier.